# Q then() always calls fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

Why does 'good' and 'Error is called' write the console in the below example?

My understanding is that you give then() something to run on success and something to run on fail?

```
var deferred = Q.defer();

function two() {
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
}

two().then(console.log('good'),console.log('Error is called'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Q.then` function can actually accept three parameters](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#progress-notification) and *all of them should be functions*.

1. The success handler
2. The failure handler
3. The progress handler

When you do,

```
two().then(console.log('good'), console.log('Error is called'));
```

you are actually passing the result of executing both the `console.log`s to the `then` function. The `console.log` function returns `undefined`. So, effectively, you are doing this

```
var first  = console.log('good');              // good
var second = console.log('Error is called');   // Error is called
console.log(first, second);                    // undefined, undefined
two().then(first, second);                     // Passing undefineds
```

So, you must be passing two functions to the `then` function. Like this

```
two().then(function() {
    // Success handler
    console.log('good');
}, function() {
    // Failure handler
    console.log('Error is called')
});
```

But, `Q` actually provides a convenient way to handle all the errors occur in the promises at a single point. This lets the developer not to worry much about error handling in the business logic part. That can be done with [`Q.fail`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#handling-errors) function, like this

```
two()
    .then(function() {
        // Success handler
        console.log('good');
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // Failure handler
        console.log('Error is called')
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass **functions** to `.then`. What you did is you called `console.log('good')` and passed the result of calling it (which is `undefined)` to `.then`. Use it like that:

```
two().then(
    function() { console.log('good'); },
    function() { console.log('Error is called'); }
);
```